# CSS color element not being reset when list item hover is finished

Tags: html, css

I have a menu structure, shown below:

```
<div id="navigation">
            <ul id="nav" class="newmenu">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="styling.html">HTML Styling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="column.html">Column Layouts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example Dropdown</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">More Menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">More Menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">More Menu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Property</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="property-list.html">Property List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="property-grid.html">Property Grid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="property-details.html">Property Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end #navigation-->
```

To this I apply some CSS, which is a bit too long to post here, so I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAHfC/3/).

The CSS lines I'm interested in are towards the top:

```
.newmenu > li > a {color:#14bbea;}
.newmenu li {background-color:White; color:#171717;}
.newmenu > li {background-color: transparent; color:#14bbea;}
.newmenu > li:hover > a {background-color: #14bbea; color:#fff;}
```

In jsfiddle it seems to work perfectly, but in any browser I test (IE, FF, Chrome) I have the following problem: When the user leaves a submenu, the background which is applied to the top item in this line:

```
.newmenu > li:hover > a {background-color: #14bbea; color:#fff;}
```

is removed, but the color does not change back to #14bbea

I can't work out why only this is not being changed back when the user is no longer hovering over the child item.

Comment: Do you have any `mouseover`/hover JavaScript functions in place?

Comment: No, there is no javascript on the page at all.